# Solving equations with modulus sign

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

How do we solve a equation such as
$$|x^2-4x+3|=x^2-4x+3$$

What are the most necessary steps to written,when solving such a question in a pure mathematics paper?

Comment: For $a\in \mathbb{R}$, note that  $|a|=a$ if and only if $a\geq 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $|x| = x\;,$ when $x\geq 0$

So $|x^2-4x+3| = x^2-4x+3\Rightarrow x^2-4x+3\geq 0$

So $(x-1)(x-3)\geq 0$

So $x\leq 1\cup x\geq 3$

Comment: And can we solve a equation such as | x-3 | > |2x-4 | by taking (x-3)^2 > (2x-4)^2

Comment: yes you can solve it